# Putting labels inside section headings

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, lyx, labels

I usually work with LyX, and when I want to label a section (in order to reference it later), I put the label inside the section heading. This usually works, but recently I tried to create an article using the "Econometrica article" layout, and got a compilation error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.4 \section{\label{sec:The-Model}The Model}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{ectaart}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{\label{sec:The-Model}The Model}
\end{document}
```

(Note: the Econometrica layout comes with LyX installation in an Unavailable status, until one installs the ectaart.cls file).

Comment: I had an identical problem, and following David Carlisle below updated my labels to ALLCAPS, like `\section{The Title\label{SEC:TITLE}}`. Of course it's only necessary to do this for the references, but this way LyX doesn't complain about broken refs.

Comment: Just as an FYI. When putting the label inside a \section{}, this can conflict with existing classes. E.g., in my case this conflicted with the latex template of an academic journal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is actually failing in the `\MakeUppercase` in the page head. If you add

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
```

then `\label` is safe in such contexts.

Comment: would this work with `\MakeTextUppercase` and `\uppercasenonmath`?  unless both of those work without side effects, i can't recommend embedding `\label` within any heading, from `\title` on down through `\section', at least not if ams document classes are involved.  similarly with the headings of theorem-class objects.

Comment: @barbarabeeton MakeTeXuppercase works (the `overload` option mentioned just defines MakeUppercase to be MaketextUppercase) by default `\uppercasenomath` would not but it looks like that redefines itself if maketextuppercase is available \AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifundefined{MakeTextUppercase}{}{\let\uppercasenonmath\altucnm}%
}

Comment: Thanks, this also worked, but, I could not understand why it worked... can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 8):

You should not use the `\label` command inside the `\section` command. Instead, you should place the `\label` command within the section itself.

It doesn't matter where in the section you place it but to avoid confusion it is better to place it just after the `\section{<title>}` command.

Here is an MWE with which you can play (uncomment one of the `\label{foo}` and comment on the other) and see that it doesn't matter where the `\label` is, the output is always the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{foo}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{\label{bar}This is a figure}
\end{figure}

%\label{foo}

\lipsum[2]
{\Huge\bfseries This is section~\ref{bar}.}

%\label{foo}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image: Output]

**NOTE** I know I did not use the `etcaart` class for the example but the considerations presented above are sort of class-independent, and should also work with the `etcaart` class (even though I haven't tried it).

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I still wonder, though, why it worked when I used the article class.

Comment: Putting `\label` in the section head is supposed to work, just as putting in the `\caption` is. Placing it after either construct can complicate getting the vertical spacing right in some layouts.