# Make \ref from a \label made on an item refer to the section/subsection, not the item number

Tags: hyperref

I would like to label an item in an enumerate then later refer to the item number (i)-(iv) but also sometimes the section it's contained in? Is there anyway to do this? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec}

\subsection{test1}\label{subsec}

\subsubsection{test2}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item
    one \label{item}
  \item
    two
\end{enumerate}


This \ref{sec} should say (1), this \ref{subsec} should say (1.1) and this \ref{item} should say (1.1.1)


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want the reference to the item to be `1.1.1` how is your reader to know if it references an item or the subsubsection?

Comment: well while it is possible I think you shouldn't do it. Imho that is confusing. Is 1.1 then a subsection or a reference to a list item in section 1? Better be explicit and write \ref{item} in subsection \ref{subsec}.

Comment: Item 1.1.1 shouldn't exist, I have added the enum style so they will be labelled only (i)-(v). Sometimes I want to reference (i), others I just want to point to the section

Comment: Just to give more context I am using this to track where abbreviations first appear. I use \label{ABC} to label new abbreviations, then I want to reference the section and page said abbreviation first appeared in, by using \ref{ABC}, and \pageref{ABC}

Comment: technically the item would be 1.1.1.ii or something similar, I am fine for the item to just be referenced as ii some times, and 1.1.1 other times. I assume I will need a new command specifically for \refitem{} to give me the two different behaviours

Comment: I think it is not such a strange request, as I understand it would be the same as `\pageref` but then for section numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following implements two approaches: one where `\ref{X}` refers to the original item number and `\ref{secX}` refers to the section the item is in, and conversely an approach where `\ref{X}` refers to the section an item is in and `\ref{itemX}` refers to the original item number.

For both variants I defined a helper command `\secref{X}` which expands to `\ref{secX}` and `\refitem{X}` that expands to `\ref{itemX}`.

I didn't redefine `\label` as that would have unwanted consequences, instead I defined new commands `\labelwithsec` and `\labelwithitem` for the two approaches.

It works by storing the current label number `\@currentlabel` (which is defined by all label-aware commands, such as `\item` or `\section`) in a temporary command, then changing the current label to the current section number (taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141369/), and then calling `\label` so that the desired number is associated to the label in the `.aux` file. Finally the label name is restored to the original one to allow subsequent `\label` commands to behave normally.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% command \getCurrentSectionNumber adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141369/
\newcommand{\getCurrentSectionNumber}{%
  \ifnum\c@subsection=0 %
  \thesection
  \else
  \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0 %
  \thesubsection
  \else
  \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  \fi
}

% Approach 1: \ref{X} is the original item label,
% \ref{secX} and \secref{X} are the section for item X
\newcommand{\labelwithsec}[1]{%
\label{#1}%
\edef\prevlabel{\@currentlabel}%
\edef\@currentlabel{\getCurrentSectionNumber}%
\label{sec#1}%
\edef\@currentlabel{\prevlabel}%
}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
\ref{sec#1}%
}

% Approach 2: \ref{X} is the section for item X,
% \ref{itemX} and \refitem{X} are the original item label
\newcommand{\labelwithitem}[1]{%
\label{item#1}%
\edef\prevlabel{\@currentlabel}%
\edef\@currentlabel{\getCurrentSectionNumber}%
\label{#1}%
\edef\@currentlabel{\prevlabel}%
}

\newcommand{\refitem}[1]{%
\ref{item#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec}

\subsection{test1}\label{subsec}

\subsubsection{test2}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item
    one \labelwithsec{itemone}
  \item
    two \labelwithitem{itemtwo}
\end{enumerate}


This \ref{sec} should say (1), this \ref{subsec} should say (1.1) and \ref{itemone} is in section \ref{secitemone}, also accessible with \secref{itemone}.

There is another item in section \ref{itemtwo} with item number \refitem{itemtwo}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the hyperlink still points at the actual item, and not to the section. This could be seen as desirable, but if you want to link to the section instead then it becomes a bit more complicated because you would also need to keep track of the section anchors (which `\thesection` etc. do not do, they store the number only).

Note also that this may result in duplicate labels which you didn't define yourself. If you have a section `\section{Introduction}\label{secintro}` for example and an item `\item xyz \labelwithsec{intro}` then you will get a warning about an already defined label even though you chose different names yourself.

Comment: This is perfect, a lot of these commands I had not seen before, limiting my ability to implement this solution. Thank you for demonstrating them in a full solution.